# Reporting confidence intervals equal to zero, should they precede a minus sign given by R?

Tags: confidence-interval, reporting

I have an effect size as follows:

0.0 [-0.0; 0.1]

Should I report minus sign or not here?

Comment: Is `[-0.0; 0.1]` the reported confidence interval ? There seems to be a rounding issue. Do you have the numbers with more decimal places ?  It wouldn't make sense to write `-0.0` for a lower bound. Since the point estimate is zero (to 1dp), the lower bound for the CI should be less than zero.

Comment: Reporting more decimal places is surely the key here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a rounding issue, of course,but also a reporting issue. Using R:

```
round(-0.00100, c(0, 1, 2, 3))
[1]  0.000  0.000  0.000 -0.001
```

which is not what I expected, but probably R will not print $-0$ never (?) At the hardware level, computers do represent both $0$ and $-0$ differently. To me, nevertheless, $-0$ means *negative but rounded to zero*. That is useful information, and could well be reported as such, but would need an explication.

In meteorology, it is common and required to report (when temperature is reported rounded to whole numbers (and in Celsius)), to  write *below zero, but rounded to zero* as $-0$.

Comment: Why did you not expect this result from `round`?  As far as "not print $-0$ ever" is concerned, try `sprintf("%.0f", -0.1)`.  (One lesson: rounding, which is a *numerical* operation, differs from printing, which involves a *formatting* operation.)

Comment: @whuber I was thinking that either the OP is using a package that uses `sprintf` or something similar, or they have written their own code that does so.

Comment: @kjetil that's an interesting convention in meteorology, but I still wonder how the point estimate can be 0.0 and the lower bound of the CI be -0.0. The R code that produced this would probably be quite enlightenning

Comment: @Robert `sprintf("%.1f", c(Estimate=0.04, LCL=-0.01, UCL=0.09))` reveals one way this output might arise with a symmetric confidence interval.

Comment: This was the secret code: df %>% mutate(one_digit = paste0(sprintf("%.1f", Estimate), " [",sprintf("%.1f", Q2.5),"; ", sprintf("%.1f", Q97.5),"]"))